# Div tag with editable text area is taking input from right to left

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

We have a div tag which contains innerHTML and while editing the text area which is inside the div tag, the input is getting printing from right to left and the cursor stands at the beginning of the text area. How to resolve this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaDre.png

HTML :
`<div [innerHTML]="description" contenteditable="true" class="form-control stnd-textarea" id="controlDivTextArea" name="note" maxlength="4000" (input)="validateDescription($event.target.innerHTML)"></div>`

CSS :

```
    -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
    -webkit-appearance: textarea;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font: medium -moz-fixed;
    font: -webkit-small-control;
    height: 155px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    resize: both;
    width: 500px;
```

Comment: it's working fine in my browser

Comment: We tried in Chrome and Edge. It is not working.

Comment: Are your browsers/your OS configured in RTL somewhere? This code works fine.

Comment: It is not RTL enabled. @WillAlexander